# Getting visa to Japan from Shanghai

Tags: visas, japan, shanghai

I'm going to stay in Shanghai on a student visa from February to June. I want to travel to Japan while I'm in Shanghai. I'm a citizen of Kazakhstan, how can I apply for a visa to Japan in Shanghai? Is it possible? What are the requirements?

Answer (score 2):

I realise this isn't a full answer to your question, but I hope it helps.

I had a look on the Shanghai embassy of Japan page, which doesn't say either way. However, the Japanese embassy in the UK sheds some light on the matter, and so this **may** apply to you.

If you have a **long term visa** for the UK (i.e. you aren't a tourist) then you **can** apply for a Japanese visa from the local UK embassy. This would suggest if you have a non-tourist visa for China (which you do as a student) then you can apply at the Shanghai embassy.

If you are in the UK as a tourist then you **can't** apply for a Japanese tourist visa as a foreign national - you need to apply through the Japanese embassy in your own country.

Whether or not the same rules apply at the Shanghai embassy, I can't say. I'd suggest you (or a Chinese friend) contact them on keizai@pk.mofa.go.jp, or on 010-8531-9800.

However, as you're not in China yet I'd suggest applying for a tourist visa now through the Kazakh-Japanese embassy - see http://www.kz.emb-japan.go.jp/visa-tourism/visa.htm.

Comment: The Japanese embassy in Singapore only allows visa applications from residents of Singapore as [explained here](http://www.sg.emb-japan.go.jp/visa_eligibility.htm). Chances are that China will be the same, and that any application will have to be done through the Japanese embassy in Kazakhstan prior to going to China.

Comment: In that case, almost certainly better to do ahead of time!

Comment: Then again, depending on the residential status while in China, it's possible that being there as a student could count as a resident and make it possible to apply there. I would recommend calling your Japanese embassy in Kazakhstan and asking them. Usually they are very helpful (and should speak your language).